# Vuetify v-btn component appears different with nuxt attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

The v-btn (vuetify) component is displayed differently if it has the "nuxt" attribute (to be used as a  in the nuxt.js framework).

How to fix it?

The first image is the v-btn component without the "nuxt" (as it should display normally) and the second has the attribute.

[image: First case :]

```
<v-btn
    class="enter-btn"
    large
    color="error"
    :disabled="!agreed"
>
    Accept and Enter
</v-btn>
```

[image: Second case :]

```
<v-btn
    class="enter-btn"
    large
    color="error"
    :disabled="!agreed"
    nuxt
    to="/to/url"
>
    Accept and Enter
</v-btn>
```

Comment: are you using another CSS library in nuxt project?

Comment: Yes, bootstrap-vue.

Comment: so, there's a conflict between the vuetify css and bootstrap css

Comment: What indications do you have that this might be the case?

Comment: try to use one library since that will mess your project and it gives you multiple issues like inadequate display

Comment: No collision with bootstrap-view is apparently involved. I removed the library and the problem still persists.

Comment: could you extend this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nuxt/codesandbox-nuxt/tree/master/) in order to debug the issue

Answer (score 0):

When the `nuxt` and `to` attributes are added, the element changes from `<button ...>` to `<a href="/to/url" ... >`.

Unfortunately adding the two code samples to a fresh project does not show the visual difference you have.
The `<a>` has an additional class `v-btn--router`, but it doesn't cause the width difference or text alignment issues.

You can debug a little by inspecting each element in the console, looking at the Styles pane and checking for any sources of style (on the RHS) other than Vuetify ones, which are `VBtn.sass` & `VApp.sass`.

Since width is one of the problem attributes, it is also worth while checking the `width` value in the Computed tab.
If it is being set directly by something, you can click it open to see the source of it's value (for example, height is set to 44px by classes `.v-btn:not(.v-btn--round).v-size--large` in the file `VBtn.sass`).